# why does this give junk characters?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in visual studio.By this code ,i want to change the first letter of words in a string to capital letter and then print them(just capital one). this does it but gives junk characters too.this is the code.help me please.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

 char ToUpper(char input){
    char output;
    output = input - ('a'-'A');
    return output;
 }
void main (viod){
    char name[40],name2[10] ;
    int length,i,j,a,b;
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);
    printf("original input:%s\n",name);
    length = strlen(name);
    if(name[0]!=' '){
        name2[0]=ToUpper(name[0]);
        a=1;b=1;
    }
    else{
        a=1; b=0 ;                                          
    }
    for(i=a,j=b;i<=length;i++){
        if(name[i]!=' '){
            if(name[i-1]==' '){
                 name2[j]=ToUpper(name[i]);
                 j++;
  }
    }
    }
    printf("%s",name2);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);` -> `scanf("%39[^\n]",name);` - There are a lot of `scanf` questions today! Please read the manual page - `scanf` is tricky to say the least

Comment: You should decide if you're writing C or C++. They're different languages.

Comment: What would happen if you apply `ToUpper` to a character other than an upper-case character?

Comment: `void main(viod)` does this even compile?

Comment: @Ajay, it probably will as a function is declared as `void` with a parameter `viod` that will default to `int` (at least on older compilers....)

Comment: Think about how many characters you're *copying* from `name` to `name2`. (Also think about whether you need to copy anything at all.)

Comment: how does the `name2` suddenly get copies of all those characters that *didn't* follow a `' '`,  from `name`?

Comment: 1) `i<=length` --> `i<length` 2) The C-String must end with a NUL character.

Comment: 3) `char name[40],name2[10];` --> `char name[40] = "", name2[10] = "";`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh yes! That is with K&R style of declarations?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char ToUpper(char input){
    return toupper(input); // using inbuilt function
}

void main() {
    char name[40]; // no need to create name2 array
    int i;
    scanf("%39[^\n]S", name); // you can use gets(name);
    printf("The original input:%s\n", name);
    for(i=0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || name[i-1] == ' ' && name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z')
            name[i] = ToUpper(name[i]); // or direct toupper(name[i]); 
    }
    printf("%s", name); // you can use puts(name);
    getch();
}
```